# Install package with Pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm trying to use cryptography package in Python in virenv but VsCode error is " no module with this name : Crypt.py(script) and Pipfile are in the same directory

```
...my direcotry > pipenv install cryptography 
....>

crypt.py

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet 
key = Fernet.generate_key()
print(key)
```

error :

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
cryptography = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're running python within the virtual env you set up with Pipenv:

```
pipenv run python my_script.py
```